# Compresión de archivos para tfg

Tags: zip

Acabo de terminar el grado superior en desarrollo de aplicaciones multiplataforma y había pensado con un compañero en para el tfg desarrollar un programa de compresión de archivos. En un principio habíamos pensado en crear nuestro propio tipo de archivo comprimido con nuestra extensión propia y hacer toda la lógica utilizando algoritmos de compresión, pero no sabemos hasta que punto es esto viable. Quería saber si alguien sabe del tema y/o ha trabajado en algo similar. De todas formas, también habíamos pensado en crear un programa que comprima en .zip y tirando, pero la primera idea es la que más nos llama la atención y un reto que queremos proponernos. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.